# Update all values of PHP array having same index

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => 
                    [user_id] => ZGNjBQN9ac3K
                    [owner_id] => 15157
                    [tagged_field] => description
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 12:11:54
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => 
                    [user_id] => ZGNjAmD9ac3K
                    [owner_id] => 15157
                    [tagged_field] => description
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 12:11:54
                )

        )

)
```

I generate this structure before saving topics so i will get topic id only after this.

So in-order to save this array i need to set topic id to all index "topic_id"... lets say if topic_id is 11234 i need to updated all index with topic_id with value 11234.

Desired Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => 11234
                    [user_id] => ZGNjBQN9ac3K
                    [owner_id] => 15157
                    [tagged_field] => description
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 12:11:54
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => 11234
                    [user_id] => ZGNjAmD9ac3K
                    [owner_id] => 15157
                    [tagged_field] => description
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 12:11:54
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Which index you want to update?

Comment: `foreach` is your friend.

Comment: Can you please post the code which generated your array structure??

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$indexedArray = array();
foreach($yourArray as $value) {
   foreach($value as $val) {
      $indexedArray[$val['topic_id']][] = $val;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simple way using **[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)** variable like

```
$yourArray = array(array(array("topic_id"=>"","user_id"=>110),array("topic_id"=>"","user_id"=>786)));

foreach($yourArray as &$value) {
   foreach($value as &$val) {
      $val['topic_id'] = "your_topic_id";
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => your_topic_id
                    [user_id] => 110
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [topic_id] => your_topic_id
                    [user_id] => 786
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use references in both `foreach` loops:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
      array("topic_id" => "", "user_id" => "ZGNjBQN9ac3K", "owner_id" => "15157", "tagged_field" => "description", "created_date" => "2015-02-06 12:11:54"),
      array("topic_id" => "", "user_id" => "ZGNjBQN9ac3K", "owner_id" => "15157", "tagged_field" => "description", "created_date" => "2015-02-06 12:11:54"),
    )
);

foreach($arr as &$value) {
   foreach($value as &$val) {
      $val['topic_id'] = $newvalue;
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```